# IE 8 bug in menu

Tags: menu, internet-explorer-8

I have a website which has to be working on all browsers. I am designing a menu like the below image

[image]

I made this menu by using the following html and css code

Html

```
 <ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/ico1.png" alt="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
 li><a href="#"><img src="images/ico2.png" alt="products"><span>Products</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/ico3.png" alt="Quality Assurance"><span>Quality Assurance</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/ico4.png" alt="Gallery"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/ico5.png" alt="Contact"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Css

```
.menu { float:left;}
.menu li {float: left;padding: 19px 45px; background:url(../images/seperator.png) no-repeat right;}
.menu li.last{ background:none !important;}
.menu li a { text-decoration:none; color:#553614; font-size:18px; font-family: 'fengardo_neueregular';}
.menu li a:hover{ color:#fff;}
.menu li span { float: left; margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 9px;}
```

It works perfectly in chrome, Ie9, firefox etc. But when i check in Ie8 the menu is collapsed like the below image[image]

How do i rectify this error?

Comment: why do you ise a image for those seperators?

Comment: @DiederikEEn I think image seperators is not a problem here. Because i tried it without seperators

Answer (score 0):

don't have ie8 at my disposal currently, but after looking @ your markup/styles here are my thoughts:
1. the misalignment is more than likely margin-padding issues...looks like there is not enough room for the `span`s on the same line as the icon, and this break is amplifying it because once the `span`s are pushed off that line, they have `margin-top` declared, which is just pushing them farther away.

You have a few options here: 1st of all, target the menu in IE8 with conditional comments; illuminate the involved elements (i like to use contrasting bgs/borders/etc., whatever makes each element stand out from the group) and inspect them in F12...if the answer(s) isn't obvious off the bat, start comparing physical pixel sizes to another browser. So if you use Chrome in this case...you can find an element's dimensions by hovering over if Developer Tools are open...how does Chrome's size(s) compare to IE8's size(s)? If they sizes are not disparate, repeat this process for the same elements, only checking positioning, layout, padding, and margins. (@ least) One of these should not match up to the other browser. You're going to want to compensate for the user agent rendering differences, and this is achievable using the conditional comments we've already used to target the menu. So lets pretend that all the `li` elements are vaguely 130px wide...if you notice that they're only 115px in IE, apply 15 more pixels of width to IE8 and only IE8 via the cc's.

i'm rambling bc i suck, but i'll try and wrap this up...your markup example is missing an opening bracket on the second `li`, prolly want to fix that first before you do anything else.

ditch the padding on the `li`s. also, apply `display:inline` to them and make your anchors `display:block; float:left`...that's a super easy to way to get rid of and/or test margin/padding issues.

i'd also place the icon into the `a` as `background-image`s...that's me being particular, but that's actually a solution to your problem too...the `span`s can't collide with the `img`s if there are no more `img` elements in the markup.

another possible easy solution here: the `span`s are floating left and applying a left margin...simply having the float:right *could* be a solution; floating them right and ditching the `margin-left` would be my second attempt, if simply `float:right` didn't resolve it.